# Java play again and else error?

Tags: java, if-statement, intersection, difference

My program is supposed to receive 2 sets of numbers from the user, find the intersection and the difference between the two sets and then ask the user if he or she want to play it again. I'm having an issue trying to get my program to play again and I can't figure out why all I know is that I keep getting the "syntax error on token "else", delete this token" and I don't know why I keep getting this error please help.

```
import java.util.*;
```

`public class Sets {
    private static final int MAXSIZE = 20;// the maximum size of the array is 20
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] resultSet = new int[MAXSIZE];
    int[] setA = new int[MAXSIZE];
    int y=0;

    System.out.print("How many numbers will be in the first set? ");
    int sizeA = keyboard.nextInt();//enter the numbers for the first set
    while (sizeA < 1 || sizeA > MAXSIZE) {//a number larger than 20 can't be entered
        System.out.print("Size is not valid, please try again: ");
        sizeA = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    getData(setA, sizeA);
    sort(setA,sizeA);

    printData(setA,sizeA);

    int[] setB = new int[MAXSIZE];
    System.out.print("How many numbers will be in the second set? ");
    int sizeB = keyboard.nextInt();//enter the numbers for the second set
    while (sizeB < 1 || sizeB > MAXSIZE) {
        System.out.print("Size is not valid, please try again: ");
        sizeB = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    getData(setB, sizeB);//go to get getData method
    sort(setB,sizeB);
    System.out.println("The intersection is: ");
    int temp = intersection(setA,sizeA,setB,sizeB,resultSet);
    printData(resultSet, temp);
    System.out.println("The difference is: ");
    temp = difference(setA,sizeA,setB,sizeB,resultSet);
    printData(resultSet, temp);
    System.out.println("Do you want to repeat the program again with two different sets (y or n)?");
    int playAgain = keyboard.nextInt();
    if ("y" != null )       
        main(args);
}
else{
            break;
    }


public static void getData(int[] set, int size) {
    // This method will retrieve "size" number of unique integers from the
    // keyboard.
    // The integers will be placed into the array set.
    int temp, uniqueNum = 0;
    while (uniqueNum < size) {
        boolean flag = true;
        temp = keyboard.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < uniqueNum; i++) {
            if (temp == set[i]) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag) {
            set[uniqueNum] = temp;
            uniqueNum++;

        }
    }

}

public static int intersection(int[] setA, int sizeA, int[] setB,
        int sizeB, int[] resultSet) {
    // This method will calculate the intersection of sets A and B.
    int found = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < sizeB; y++) {
            if (setA[x] == setB[y]) {
                resultSet[found] = setA[x];
                found++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return found;
}

public static int difference(int[] setA, int sizeA, int[] setB, int sizeB,
        int[] resultSet) {
    // This method will calculate the difference (A-B) of the two sets.
    int found = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++) {
        boolean flag = true;
        for (int y = 0; y < sizeB; y++) {
            if (setA[x] == setB[y]) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag) {
            resultSet[found] = setA[x];
            found++;
        }

    }

    return found;
}

public static void sort(int[] nums, int size) {
    // This method will sort the elements in the nums array into ascending
    // order.
    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++) {
        int integer = count;
        int B = nums[count];
        while ((integer > 0) && (nums[integer - 1] > B)) {
            nums[integer] = nums[integer - 1];
            integer--;
        }
        nums[integer] = B;
    }
}

public static void printData(int[] set, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        System.out.print(set[i] + " ");
    System.out.println("");

}
```

}

Comment: Please avoid using Stack Overflow as a crowd sourced debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing opening bracket (`{`) after if:

```
if ("y" != null )
```

So the following closing bracket actually ends the method

```
        main(args);
} // method ended here
else{
            break;
    }
```

and your `else` is no mans land, which compiler does not like.